# Windows 7 Driver for Bluetooth on LG G3

Tags: bluetooth, windows, lg-g3, bluetooth-pairing

I tried today to connect my LG G3 phone to my PC running Windows 7 64 bits, via bluetooth. I could not find any fitting bluetooth driver anywhere: neither on windows update or LG.com, nor on any other reasonably reliable website. Therefore, it is impossible to explore the content of my phone from my PC without cable, and for example send an MP3 file quickly to it, which is the feature I was looking for.

What is even more alarming, is that almost no one reported this problem on the web. Am I the only one who likes to update his music list on his phone this way?

Does anyone know why it is so, or whether there actually is a driver I was unaware of? Did LG give up on Bluetooth pairing with a computer, leaving only wireless headphones as an application for Bluetooth? I find it really weird...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be specific to LG. I've never been able to figure out how to transfer or browse my previous phone's (Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, currently on LG G3) filesystem over bluetooth.


Looks like this is one of those unsolved problem on Android.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194039/android-how-can-i-browse-remote-device-file-system-via-bluetooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not the only one. Following the steps below did the trick for me (taken originally from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/bluetooth-peripheral-device-driver-not-found/7d14b9b9-d2d2-484a-9d05-13f70512c6cc)):

> 1 - Download the 'Windows Mobile Device Center' (current version is
>   6.1) which you can download it [here for 32-bit OS](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/downloads/microsoft/device-center-download.mspx) or [here for 64-bit OS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3182). This works for both Vista and Windows 7. I've tried it on both.
>
> 2 - Install the downloaded software but it may not look like it worked
>   on Windows 7 PCs. Vista automatically configured the settings on the
>   bluetooth devices but for those who have Windows 7, here are the
>   things you should do:
>
> 3 - Go to 'Device Manager' from 'Control Panel' -Or- just right-click
>   on Computer Icon and choose 'Properties' and then click on 'Device
>   Manager'.
>
> 4 - You'll see an 'Unknown Device' named 'Bluetooth Peripheral Device'
>
> 5 - Right-Click it and click on "Update Driver Software" -Or- anyway
>   you find it easy to bring up the Update driver window.
>
> - Click "Browse My Computer Image for Driver Software" button.
> - Click "Let Me Pick from a List of Device Drivers on my computer".
> - Select 'Bluetooth Radio' from the list if it asked you to select and then in the next window, it will show a list of drivers with Company
>     Names in one list and Drivers in another. In the Company List choose
>     'Microsoft Corporation', not only Microsoft.
> - From the drivers list there may be one or more drivers with the name "Windows Mobile-Based Device Support" with different driver versions.
>     Select one or the latest.
> - Ignore any warnings and keep pressing next and then Finish at last. If all goes well, the last screen will show the message that device
>     driver is successfully installed.

After doing this and pairing my PC and phone again, I was able to send files between them through bluetooth.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I installed the Windows Mobile Device Center, actually removed the phone as a peripheral and reinstalled it, today (Apr 2016) 2 out of 3 drivers were actually found on Windows Update, and I used your method for the 3rd one. I still cannot explore the phone from windows explorer, but I noticed an option by right clicking the system tray bluetooth icon: send and receive files. And it works. So I can send and receive files; but is there a way to mount the phone in the windows explorer, without weird 3rd party apps?

Comment: I don't have that win 7 pc anymore, so I can't check that for you. But as far as I remember, that was the only way that worked for me.